# Events not working in minimized window extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, dom-events, extjs4.2

I have added events `beforeclose` and `beforedestroy` for a window which work perfectly fine when the window is in expanded state. But the same are not triggered when window is minimized and I press the close button. How to achieve this ?

```
var popupwindow =   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                itemId : 'popupwindow',
                width: 1500,
                height: 700,
                minimizable:true,
                layout:{
                    type : 'hbox',
                    align : 'stretch',
                },
                autoShow: true,
                items : [
                {
                     xtype : 'container',
                     flex  : 2,
                     items : [item],
                     layout : 'fit'
                 },
                 {
                    html:'<div id="containerDiv"/>',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    flex : 1
                }],
                listeners : {
                    afterrender : function(){
                        //do something
                    },
                    minimize: function (window) {
                        //even this is not getting triggered
                    },
                    beforeclose : function(panel, event) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            });
        }
popupwindow.show();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, minimization is the behavior that we set ourselves. Please show how you minimize the window. My example with working beforeclose and beforedestroy events https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33ik

Comment: @pvlt edited to add how I am creating window.

Comment: minimize: function (window) {
                        //even this is not getting triggered
                    },

In `minimize` you must create your oun minimization logic. look at my fiddle from prev comment

Comment: @pvlt thank you. but can't see maximize button when it is collapsed even though maximizable is set to true

Comment: It's happen due `afterCollapse`  `window`'s method.
https://i.imgur.com/ZXQFtqU.png
slightly changed the fiddle

Comment: better not to hide `maximize` tool. he begins to behave unpredictably

Comment: oh wow. thanks a lot !